# SQL select latest row from multiple inner join with Optional parameters SP

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

i have the following tables :

```
Locations
_________________
Location_ID,
TrackingVehicle_ID,
GPS_Time,
Longitude,
Latitude,
Speed,
Angle,
LocationStatus_No,
IgnitionStatus_No,
Address,
Distance,
Message_Type_No,
StreetSpeed,
Vehicle_ID,
Driver_ID.


Vehicles
___________
Vehicle_ID,
Company_ID,
PlateNumber,
VehicleType_No,
VehicleSubType_No,
Status_ID.


TrackingVehicles
___________________
TrackingVehicle_ID,
Fleet_ID,
Vehicle_ID,
Driver_ID,
MaxSpeed,
Vehicle_SN,
NavDevice_ID,
Latest_LocationID,
Latest_GPS_Time.


VehicleFences
_______________
VehicleFecne_ID,
GeoFence_ID,
Vehicle_ID.
```

i want to return the vehicles for a specific companyID, fleet, fence and IgnitionStatus.
these parameters could be null except the companyID,

i tried the following :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[testselectVehicle]
@companyId int,
   @fleetId int,
   @geofenceId int,
   @ignStatId int      
AS
BEGIN
declare @str [nvarchar](MAX) = '',
@qur [nvarchar](MAX)

IF @fleetId is not null
    BEGIN
    SET @str =@str + ' and TrackingVehicles.Fleet_ID = ''' + Convert(nvarchar,         @fleetId) + ''''
    END
    IF @geofenceId is not null
    BEGIN
    SET @str =@str + '  and vehiclefences.geofence_id = '''+ Convert(nvarchar,     @geofenceId)+''''
    END
    IF @ignStatId is not null
    BEGIN
    SET @str =@str + '  and  Locations.IgnitionStatus_No = '''+ Convert(nvarchar,     @ignStatId) +''''
    END


 set @qur =    'SELECT dbo.Locations.GPS_Time,
                       dbo.Vehicles.PlateNumber,
                       dbo.Locations.Address,
                       dbo.Locations.Speed,
                       dbo.Locations.Longitude,
                       dbo.Locations.Latitude,
                       dbo.Locations.IgnitionStatus_No
                 FROM  dbo.Locations
                 INNER JOIN  dbo.TrackingVehicles ON
             dbo.Locations.TrackingVehicle_ID = dbo.TrackingVehicles.TrackingVehicle_ID 
                INNER JOIN dbo.Vehicles ON
            dbo.Locations.Vehicle_ID =     dbo.Vehicles.Vehicle_ID AND
            dbo.TrackingVehicles.Vehicle_ID = dbo.Vehicles.Vehicle_ID
                 INNER JOIN dbo.VehicleFences ON
            dbo.Vehicles.Vehicle_ID = dbo.VehicleFences.Vehicle_ID 
            where Vehicles.Company_ID = '

set @qur = @qur + Convert(nvarchar,@companyId)                      
set @qur = @qur + @str

exec(@qur)


END
```

but 7500000 record where returned because the GPS_Time, longitude & latitude may have multiple values for the same vehicle,

i need to return the Vehicle details with the latest location (long & lat) and latest GPS_time

Comment: you can do print @qur before exec to chk actual query.what is latest meant here ?for latest you always order by column asc/desc and use top n.

Comment: @KumarHarsh,
the latest i meant here is the latest entry for GPS_Time, Long & Lat,

Comment: if i used top(1), then the query will return the 7500000 record first then return the top(1) based on it, which will take 2 minutes to execute

Comment: All i need to return is every Vehicle with its Details and latest location for specific Company

Comment: use row_number() over(partition by gpstime order by gpstime desc).i am not sure about "partition by what" coz i am not sure about your data.but this thing will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `row_number()` function to enumerate the locations and then choose the first one:

```
SELECT l.GPS_Time, v.PlateNumber, l.Address, l.Speed, l.Longitude, l.Latitude, l.IgnitionStatus_No
FROM (select l.*,
             row_number() over (partition by TrackingVehicle_ID
                                order by GPS_Time desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from dbo.Locations l
     ) l inner join
     dbo.TrackingVehicles tv
     on l.TrackingVehicle_ID = tv.TrackingVehicle_ID and l.seqnum = 1 inner join
     dbo.Vehicles v
     on tv.Vehicle_ID = v.Vehicle_ID inner join
     dbo.VehicleFences vf
     on v.Vehicle_ID = vf.Vehicle_ID 
where Vehicles.Company_ID . . .
```

I also simplified the query by using table aliases and removing an extra, redundant `join` condition on the `Vehicles` table.

Comment: Thank You. :)
i added distinct to the first select and it worked correctly,
but for i have more than 10 million records in Table Locations, it took 4:30 to execute.
is there a faster way to do it ?

Comment: @user1929505 . . . Try asking this as another question.  Include the layouts of the tables (in particular, any indexes that you have on the tables) and the sizes of each table.

Answer (score 0):

To only include the last GPS_Time per vehicle you can add an inner join to a subquery with that last GPS_Time per vehicle:

```
...INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT TrackingVehicle_ID, MAX(GPS_Time) GPS_Time 
    FROM Locations GROUP BY TrackingVehicle_ID) X
ON X.TrackingVehicle_ID = Locations.TrackingVehicle_ID AND X.GPS_Time= Locations.GPS_Time
```